# tratamento de multiplas promisses em angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-service, postgresql, aplicação-web

Estou desenvolvendo um código e no mesmo eu construo algumas áreas de influências para dadas localizações (com coordenadas e raio de distância ou tempo a pé a partir da coordenada), então quando concluo sua construção tenho que fazer consultas no banco de dados `postgres` para retornar as coordenadas de todos os pontos referentes a área que foi resultante da consulta, o meu problema é que tenho que tratar essas `multiplas promisses` para só depois salvar o objeto que foi construído com essas coordenadas resultantes da consulta.

Segue o código:

```
function _checkInfluenceAreas (lat, lon, influenceAreas) {
    for (let influence of influenceAreas) {
        $scope.okToCreate.push({ok: null})
        if (influence.type === 'km') _addInfluenceDist(lat, lon, influenceAreas.indexOf(influence), influence.obj)
        else if (influence.type === 'time') _addInfluenceTime(lat, lon, influenceAreas.indexOf(influence), influence.obj)
        else if (influence.type === 'handdraw') console.log('handdraw')
    }
}


function _addInfluenceDist (lat, lon, index, distObj) {
    let color = distObj.color
    let km = distObj.km * 1000
    let opacity = distObj.opacity
    let promisse = $cartodbService.drawCircleInfluence(lat, lon, km, color, opacity)
    promisse.then(res => {
  // self.locationObj.areasInfluencia[index].obj.theGeom = res.data.rows[0].st_buffer
        $cartodbService.paintCircle(lat, lon, km, color, opacity)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}

function _addInfluenceTime (lat, lon, index, timeObj) {
    let color = timeObj.color
    let time = timeObj.time * 60
    let opacity = timeObj.opacity
    let modo = timeObj.optionTime
    let xyPolyline = []
    let travelInfluence = $cartodbService.drawTravelTimeInfluence(lat, lon, color, time, opacity, modo)
    travelInfluence.then(res => {
  // self.locationObj.areasInfluencia[index].obj.theGeom = res.data.rows[0].the_geom
        let multipolyline = angular.fromJson(res.data.rows[0].st_asgeojson).coordinates
        for (let i = 0; i <= multipolyline[0][0].length - 1; i++) {
            xyPolyline.push([multipolyline[0][0][i][1], multipolyline[0][0][i][0]])
        }
        $cartodbService.paintPolygon(xyPolyline, color, opacity, 10)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
})}
```

Por favor caso alguém tenha um sugestão agradeço.

Comment: `angular` 1 ou 2?

Comment: @Sorack angular 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) para resolver um array de promessas:

```
var promessas = [];

promessas.push(promessa1);
promessas.push(promessa2);
promessas.push(promessa3);

$q.all(promessas).then(function() {
  console.log('resolveu tudo!');
});
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado pela ajuda :)